# What exception does getfield throw?

Tags: julia, field

What exception does the following piece of code throw?

```
getfield(nothing, :a)
```

`ERROR: type Nothing has no field a` seems to be only catchable via `Exception` by trial and error, every documentation left me clueless...

```
match_strings = try @. getfield(match(regex, words), :match)
catch e
    if isa(e, Exception) return false end
    throw(e)
end
```

(snippet from a function)
Follow up: Is `nothing.a` / `getproperty` easier to catch if `getfield` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws a simple `ErrorException`. You can check by catching the error and printing the type:

```
julia> try
           getfield(nothing, :a)
       catch e
           println(typeof(e))
       end
# ErrorException
```

`getproperty(nothing, :a)` throws the same, as does attempting to access property `a` via `nothing.a`.